# Show that S is an arithmetic progression, then A can be recognize as a language

Tags: dfa

A set S of nonnegative integers is called an arithmetic progresion if there exist some integers n and p such that

S = {n + ip : i ≥ 0}

Let A ⊆ {a}∗ and consider S = {| x |: x ∈ A}.

(1) Show that if S is an arithmetic progression, then A can be recognized by a

DFA

(2) Show that if A can be recognized by a DFA, then S is the union of a ﬁnite number of arithmetic

Comment: I can say with absolute certainty that your instructor wants to see *your work* and not ours. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for help.  Either you've not been attentive in class, or they've not yet done their job of providing you with the knowledge needed to complete your assignment. Good luck.

Comment: Can you at least help me understand this question? im not really looking for the answer

Comment: Whatever, the case is, you should probably be asking this question on mathematics or computer science, not stack overflow since this is not a programming question